# Your Favorite LINQ-to-Objects Queries

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects, sample

With LINQ, a lot of programming problems can be solved more easily - and in fewer lines of code.

What are some the best real-world **LINQ-to-Objects** queries that you've written?

(Best = simplicity & elegance compared to the C# 2.0 / imperative approach).

Comment: A very good question, but I think it should be wikified.

Answer (score 8):

Filter out null items in a list.

```
var nonnull = somelist.Where(a => a != null);
```

Create a dictionary where the key is the value of a property, and the value is the number of times that property appears in the list.

```
var countDictionary = somelist
    .GroupBy(a => a.SomeProperty)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: `somelist.Where(a => a != null)` is a bit less efficient than `somelist.OfType<T>()`

Answer (score 4):

LINQ is merely the addition of some functional programming concepts to C#/VB. Hence, yes, most things tend to get much easier. C# 2.0 actually had some of this -- see the List methods, for instance. (Although, anonymous method syntax in C# 2.0 was too verbose.)

Here's one little example:

```
static readonly string badChars = "!@#$%^&*()";
bool IsUserNameValid(string userName) {
  return userName.Intersect(badChars).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Example 1**

Returns list with names of all available instances of SQL Server within the local network

```
private List<string> GetServerNames()
{
    return SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources().Rows.
        Cast<DataRow>().
        Select
        (
            row => row["ServerName"].ToString() + 
                  (row["InstanceName"] != DBNull.Value ? "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString() : "") + 
                  (row["Version"] != DBNull.Value ? " (" + row["Version"].ToString().Substring(0, 3) + ")" : "")
        ).
        OrderBy(s => s).
        ToList();
}
```

**Example 2**

Generates not used name for new file

```
private string NewName(string newNamePrefix, List<string> existingFileNames)
{
    return newNamePrefix + 
        (existingFileNames.
            Select
            (
                n =>
                {
                    if (n.StartsWith(newNamePrefix))
                    {
                        int i;
                        if (int.TryParse(n.Replace(newNamePrefix, ""), out i))
                            return i;
                    }

                    return 0;
                }
            ).
            OrderBy(i => i).
            Last() + 1
        );
}
```

Comment: Which reference do you need for the 1st example? I've tried it in LinqPad but it is missing an assembly reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have two nicely absurd but elegant examples that I love

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> Information(this byte x)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => ((x >> i) & 1) == 1);
}

public static IEnumerable<bool> Information(this IEnumerable<byte> xs)
{
    return xs.SelectMany(Information);
}
```

Albeit these are encapsulated as query operators so you can reuse them, e.g. for binary parsing

```
var n = bytes.Information().Skip(3).Take(16).ToInt();
```

Comment: I see - it's a ToBits() function. Nice.

Comment: Yes; I prefer the name Information as the smallest unit of information is a bit. It should haven been an extension property though but we don't have those yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a delimited `Name=Value` string, such as `"ID=2;Name=James;Age=32;"` and you want to turn this into a dictionary quickly, you can use:

```
var dict = value.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(str => str.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list (i.e. `List<Palette> palettes`) that contains objects which contains another list (i.e. `Palette.Colors`) and want to flatten all those sub-lists into one:

```
List<Color> allColors = palettes.SelectMany(p => p.Colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got me started and its awesome!

```
var myList = from list in myObjectList select list
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting the idea. What is so special about this example?

Comment: @Matt 7 years ago that was pretty neat.

Comment: @Matt because it was a really simple, yet powerful, way to quickly iterate over of list. From there, it's easy to add where clauses, etc to _really_ get some awesome results. Code would be clean and simple to read.

Comment: @Pure.Krome/Filip Ekberg - I agree, however `var myList = myObjectList.AsQueryable();` would do the same but shorter.

Comment: @Matt, That's not LINQ though.

Comment: Ok, it is not a query, but it has the same effect as the query you provided: it converts a list of objects into a queryable datatype. You can then use myList in subsequent Linq queries, e.g. `from x in myList where x.aNumericProp>5 select x`. And btw, `.AsQueryable()` only creates 3 lines of IL code (`ldloc.0`, `call System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable`, `stloc.2`) as you can see in LinqPad's IL tab.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use LINQ on text when I'm porting code:

For example:

```
String.Join("\n", @"some VB6 code
    that I could refactor automatically
    if FindAndReplace were a bit more powerfully
    And I don't want to refactor by hand".Split('\n').Trim().Select(line =>
    {
        if(line.Contains("FindAndReplace") && !line.StartsWith("//"))
        {
            return line.Split(" ").Last();
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Join("_", line.Split(" ").Take(3));
        }
    });
```

You get the idea.  Linq lets me apply the full power of C# to text transformation.  Typically I use it when I have code in one language that I want to extract and manipulate in a complex manner, I throw the text alone in LinqPad and do a "find-replace" on quotation marks, replacing them with double quotation marks, then I surround it by `@"..."` and get to work.  I can usually do massive code transformations in 30 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is the following Linq example for **dynamically sorting a SQL table** from the [Northwind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143221%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) database:

```
void Main()
{

// Demonstrates dynamic ordering

var SortExpression = "Total"; // choose ProductName or Total
var sortAscending = true; // choose true for ascending, false for descending

// the query to sort
var data = (from pd in Products
                    join od in OrderDetails on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID into DetailsByProduct
                    select new { ProductName = pd.ProductName, Total = DetailsByProduct.Count()}).ToList();

// the data source you can use for data binding                     
var ds= (sortAscending) 
    ? data.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(SortExpression).GetValue(x, null))
    : data.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(SortExpression).GetValue(x, null));

ds.Dump();
}
```

It allows you to dynamically sort by simply specifying a field in the variable `SortExpression` and a sort order in the variable `sortAscending`.

By using `.Take(x)` and `.Skip(y)` you can as well **implement paging** easily.